# Spring SnsWebConfiguration.class could not be registered

Tags: spring-cloud

I have the following in my pom, im not sure i need to have both of these. Since i get an error on application start up that only one SnsWebConfiguration.class bean can be registered. I recently upgraded the aws dependencies to 2.3

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

error:

```
defined in class path resource [io/awspring/cloud/autoconfigure/messaging/SnsAutoConfiguration$SnsWebConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [io/awspring/cloud/messaging/config/annotation/SnsWebConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.\n\nAction:\n\nConsider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true\
```

Answer (score 0):

So i found the problem. It was related to having @EnableX annotations from previous versions. Once i removed them, it started working fine.